# How can I press keyboard buttons via selenium only for current Chrome session in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, keyboard, focus

My script opens Crome's page and presses "down" button. It occures in headless mode. If I open chrome window script focuses on it. How can I avoid that situation?

Answer (score 0):

For automalte your keyboard or mouse clicks you can use "pyautogui" module in python. You can find more about "pyautogui" module in it's docs and can contact me for more info.
Mail me on this address : gamingbomb911@gmail.com